# Is there a way to have 2 onSubmit events in React?

Tags: reactjs, onsubmit

I was wondering if anyone could explain how I can have 2 onSubmit events in React? I have a button for clicking a form on submission, and it has a thank you message popping up, but I'm trying to clear the localStorage at the same the form is submitted. I have tried this:

```
   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(`Thank you for your order! ^_^ Please check your texts for updates!`);
      toggle()
   };

   const clearCartStorage = () => {
      localStorage.clear();
   }
```

`<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit && clearCartStorage()}>`

These work separately, but when I have the && only the clearCartStorage function will run without the handleSubmit pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new function which calls those other functions:

```
<Form onSubmit={(e) => {
  handleSubmit(e);
  clearCartStorage();
})>
```

Answer (score 0):

Careful, you are invoking `clearCartStorage` when you create the Form component there.

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit && clearCartStorage()}> ❌❌❌
```

It should take one function which can call multiple.

I would set it up like this. It's more common to keep the function definition out of the returned JSX.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      clearCartStorage()
      alertUser()
      
   };

   const clearCartStorage = () => {
      localStorage.clear();
   }

   const alertUser = () => {
      alert(`Thank you for your order! ^_^ Please check your texts for updates!`);
      toggle()
   }

   return <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the responses worked. I should have posted my whole code, but what I did to fix it was create a separate component with the new function that runs the alert and clearStorage functions. Having everything on the same component within a modal div was not working.

So I basically have:

```
<Modal>

<FormComponent /> // my new function in here

</Modal>
```